# Is it possible to create a sparkline (with jquery.sparkline plugin) in an element not yet attached to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline , I am trying to

```
var attachLater = $('<div class="container">')
   .append($('<span>').sparkline([0,1,2]));
.
.
.
$('body').append(attachLater);
```

but it doesnt work. It behaves as if sparkline doesnt get called at all. On an attached element it works fine. Am I missing something, or this just isnt supported by sparkline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. I missed this part of the faq: *"How do I draw a sparkline on an element that is not yet in the DOM?"* at http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-faq

Also there is a workaround with livequery:

```
$('.sparkMePlease').livequery(function() { 
    $(this).sparkline(values, options).removeClass('sparkMePlease');
});
.
.
.
attachLater = $('<div>').addClass('sparkMePlease');
.
.
.
$('body').append(attachLater);
```